# Getting all docs from Cloudant with PHP and CURL

Tags: php, curl, couchdb, cloudant

I'm trying to fetch all the docs from my CouchDB hosted in Cloudant, using PHP and CURL.

So far I've tried this, I get a 200 status, but nothing on the Response column of the console.

```
<?php

$url = "https://myuser.cloudant.com/mydb/_all_docs?include_docs=true";
$user = 'myuser';
$pass = 'mypass';
$ch = curl_init();   // initialize curl handle
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$user:$pass");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$output = curl_exec($ch);

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
return $output;
return json_decode($output,true);   
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

I'm not fluent in PHP, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things look odd to me about the above code sample.  I usually put the credentials in the URL so https://user:pass@myuser.cloudant.com as the URL - then you don't need the following two curl_setopt lines.  I'm not exactly sure how it would work to pass those separately.

Also you're `return`ing twice.  If you just want to inspect the output try the `var_dump()` command and see if that shows you what you expect?